# Height of the dehomogenization ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider the ring $S=k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$. Let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal of $S$, and suppose there exists $i$ such that $x_i^n\notin I$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$. Set $I_i$ the dehomogenization of $I$ with respect to $x_i$. Then can we prove $\mathrm{ht}(I)=\mathrm{ht}(I_i)$? What if we further assume $I$ prime?

I know that if $I$ is prime, setting $r=\mathrm{ht}(I)$ then we have a chain of homogeneous primes with strict inclusions: $P_0\subset P_1\subset \cdots \subset P_r=I$. But will strict inclusions hold after dehomogenization?

**Edit**: Dehomogenization of $I$ with respect to $x_i$ is the defining ideal of $\mathrm{Proj}(S/I)|_{D_+(x_i)}$ as a closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Spec}{k[\frac{x_j}{x_i}]_j}$. If we pick a set of homogeneous generators $f_1,\dots,f_r$ for $I$, then the dehomogenization can be regarded as the ideal generated by $\left(\frac{f_j}{x_i^{\deg(f_j)}}\right)_j$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't define dehomogenization - you should! If you mean taking the zero-graded part of the homogeneous localization, please try any example.

Comment: @KReiser I have added the definition. if there are still confusions, please let me know.

Comment: Ok, great. Now play around: if there's some element $f$ in $P_i$ but not $P_{i-1}$, then look at $f/x_i^{\deg f}$. Which of the dehomogenizations can it be in?

Comment: @KReiser Ah, after doing some calculation I see the strict inclusion holds after doing dehomogenization. So the height of dehomogenization will not decrease. It seems that we can prove this height will not increase by defining "homogenization" of prime ideals to lift any chain of ideals in the homogeneous localization to homogeneous ideals in $S$. But is there more direct ways to prove this inequality($ht(I_i)\leq ht(I)$?